# hook_node_insert PDOException exception issue

Tags: 7, nodes, database, hooks

I am attempting to programmatically insert some field data when a new node is being created using the following code:

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {

    $dialects = array('en-AU', 'en-NZ', 'en-US');

    node_object_prepare($node);
    foreach ($dialects as $dialect) {
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['entity_id'] = $node->nid;
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['entity_type'] = 'node';
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['revision_id'] = 3;
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['language'] = $dialect;
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['source'] = 'en';
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['uid'] = 1;
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['status'] = 1;
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['translate'] = 0;
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['created'] = time();
        $node->translations->data[$dialect]['changed'] = time();

        $node->field_page_body[$dialect] = $node->field_page_body['en'];
    }
    node_save($node);       
}
```

However, I recieve the following error:

[image]

**I understand it's complaining about the same node ID being saved twice but I'm not sure how to avoid this exception and update my new node with the programmatically set data?**

It's important I execute my code at hook_node_insert because there are hundreds of nodes to be imported later and they all need the same treatment.

The same code works when tested in `mymodule_init()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the work around to this issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-03-16/how-to-modify-node-when-use-hook-node#comment-9972317).

Use `field_attach_update('node', $node);`

instead of:

`node_save($node);`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `node_save($node)` during `hook_node_insert($node)`.

According to the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x), that hook is invoked during the middle of the database transaction, so the node isn't committed to the database yet. So when you invoke node_save, the old node you're attempting to update doesn't exist yet, and it will attempt to create a new node (with the same ID). Thus, the collision.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I apologise if my question was not clear but I had already deduced that issue. My question is realy more about how I can get around this issue. I still need to insert data into the node as it is being created. I'm sure my code is implemented in the right hook but the code itself is "faulty" - what do I do to fix that?

Comment: Oh. In that case, won't hook_node_presave work for your purposes? Do you absolutely need the nid to exist for the data you're adding?

Comment: I did try hook_node_presave but the result was essentially a crash

Comment: Could you clarify? What error did you receive?

Or does it not really matter per your answer below?

Comment: I appreciate your dilligence and persistence but the problem is solved.
The error was a white screen with raw text. It was one of those that when beyond php and apache issues and shows something has absolutely gone wrong with the system.